# Why is the print statement printing None at the end

Tags: python, function

```
def empty(new):
    new1=''
    for i in new:
        new1=i+new1
        print(new1)
    print(new1)    

new='First question'
print(new)
print(empty(new))
```

output:

```
First question
F
iF
riF
sriF
tsriF
 tsriF
q tsriF
uq tsriF
euq tsriF
seuq tsriF
tseuq tsriF
itseuq tsriF
oitseuq tsriF
noitseuq tsriF
noitseuq tsriF
None
```

Question:
why do i get none at the end???

Comment: Because your function `empty` returns `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to replace `print(empty(new))` with `empty(new)`. In the first case you are printing the return value of the call to the function `empty`, which in this case is `None` because the function doesn't have a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a `return` to the function:

```
def empty(new):
    new1=''
    for i in new:
        new1=i+new1
        print(new1)
    return new1   

new='First question'
print(new)
print(empty(new))
```

Or call function not in `print`:

```
def empty(new):
    new1=''
    for i in new:
        new1=i+new1
        print(new1)
    print(new1)  

new='First question'
print(new)
empty(new)
```